# How to cast Object to Map<String, Object>, avoiding unchecked cast and illegal generic type for instanceof

Tags: java, casting

I've got my JSON neatly into a Map<String, Object>. My JSON object has two fields, one of which is a List, the other is a List<Map<String, Object>>. I want to get both of them into a variable of the appropriate type.

If I do

```
if (rows instanceof List) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) rows);
}
```

I get an "Unchecked cast". If I do:

```
if (rows instanceof List<Map<String, Object>>) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = List<Map<String, Object>>) rows);
}
```

I get "Illegal generic type for instanceof".

So what is the right way to cast this while checking that I can cast this? I've looked everywhere and I can't find a good answer to this, yet this seems like a really obvious use case that should not be impossible.

Comment: Are you saying the List could be either `List<Object>` or `list<Map<String, Object>>`?  Or do you have two lists of the two different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generic type information is not available at runtime. This is why you can't use a parameterized type with `instanceof`.

A way to work around this limitation is to check if the elements of the list are indeed instances of `Map<String, Object>.`

```
if (rows instanceof List) {
    List<?> rowsList = (List<?>) rows;
    boolean canCast = true;
    
    for (Object row : rowsList) {
        if (!(row instanceof Map)) {
            canCast = false;
            break;
        }
        
        Map<?, ?> rowMap = (Map<?, ?>) row;
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : rowMap.entrySet()) {
            if (!(entry.getKey() instanceof String) || !(entry.getValue() instanceof Object)) {
                canCast = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (canCast) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> typedRows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) rows;
        // Do something with typedRows
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Awkward and cumbersome, but I guess this is the only proper way to do it. I ended up just using `instanceof List`, ignoring the warning and blindly trusting the input after that. If I can't cast this, I'm going to have to throw an error anyway, so why not a ClassCastException?